# Pre-processor macro concatenation to build class function

Tags: c++, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I need an array of POD configuration structures containing pointers to static functions in some long-named class e.g.

```
typedef void (*MyFn)();

struct MyData {
    MyFn myFn;
    ...
};

...
struct MyData const configArr[] = {
    { ... },
    ...
};
```

The functions to be used look like `void AClass::AnotherClass::YetAnotherClass::someFn();`

I see three options:

1. make `configArr` a member of `AClass::AnotheClass::YetAnotherClass`,
2. use full name in the configuration. And I do not like either of them,
3. I tried usual two level pre-processor concatenation it complains that:

   > 'pasting "::" and "xxx" does not give a valid preprocessing token'.

The best thing I came up with was to have some common prefix for all functions used in conf.

i.e.: `AClass::...::prefSomeFn()`; and use concatenation of 'AClass::...::pref' and 'SomeFn' it works but it is still seem too ugly.

Is there any better way out?

Comment: Ditch the code generation via macro idea. Consider whether the class nesting is excessive. Add some typedefs if, after due consideration, you decide to keep that complexity. Consider namespaces as an alternative. Maybe you're using classes as namespaces. Anyway, the preprocessor limitations are not a problem: they serve to guide you away from macros, which is just right.

Comment: Better way is to get rid of: *"an array of POD configuration structures containing pointers to static functions in some long-named class"*. Really.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. However, it seems that deep nesting is somewhat unavoidable - it is large system with a lot of independent components all using the same mechanism. I do not see how namespaces could help. Also the question about generated configuration not generated code.

Comment: It might help to back up and tell us more about the actual problem you're trying to solve, at a higher level.

Comment: @JohnZwink. Top level class is managed object, next level is FSM-slice (aka orthogonal region), next level is collection of actions and guards for the FSM-slice, config-table is transition table for the FSM (similar to boost msm but suitable for much larger scale with some significant improvements). It will be nice to have transition table anonymous - for better decoupling of generated and hand-crafted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'pasting "::" and "xxx" does not give a valid preprocessing token'.

That's because they *are* separate tokens; you don't need to paste them, just put them adjacent in the expansion:

```
struct ClassWithALongName { int i; };
#define X(MemberId) &ClassWithALongName::MemberId
auto ptr = X(i);
```